# How to disable all Facebook e-mail notifications except friend requests and personal messages?

Tags: facebook, email, account-management, notifications, spam-prevention

Is there a way to disable **all** Facebook e-mail notifications, except friend requests and personal messages?

In the *Account Settings* → *Notifications* → Email section there are 2 options:

- **All notifications, except the ones you unsubscribe from**

and

- **Only notifications about your account, security and privacy**

The first option is checked. How do I "**unsubscribe from**" them?

Answer (score 1):

It's not just one place where you need to do changes, but this is roughly how you can avoid being spammed with unwanted messages from Facebook:

- **Step 1:** Go in the [Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings) page and check out the **Privacy** and **Timeline** pages to customize the privacy level so that you don't allow anyone else to perform activities on your profile (tag you in pictures and videos, mention you in posts, send you invites to applications and so on)
- **Step 2:** Go in the [Notifications](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications) settings page and change what you want to get notified about.

Answer (score -1):

You can silence specific notifications categories via the UNSUBSCRIBE link in the e-mail notification.